# Removing a specific string from an array

Tags: javascript

```
else if(input === 'remove'){
    let search = prompt('what index do you want to remove');
    for(let j=0;j<todos.length;j++){
        console.log(`current data is:${todos[j]}`);
        if(todos[j] === search){
            console.log(`data to be delete is present`)
            todos.splice(todos[j],1);
            console.log(`data deleted is ${todos[j]}`)
        }
    }
```

if todos contains [task1, abc, def]

my output is :

current data is:task1

current data is:abc

current data is:def

data to be delete is present

data deleted is undefined

How do I remove the element that is todos[j] from the list todos[]

Comment: The logic of trying to log `todos[j]` *after* you remove it from array doesn't make sense. What you are actually logging is what used to be the next element in the array (if it exists) before you removed the current one. Try inspecting the whole array instead

Comment: Also splicing in a forward looking for loop is not a good idea as you are changing the length and indexing when you do that

Comment: @charlietfl that makes sense, however, the correct element still isn't removed. 
Command : list the elements in todo 


task1
task2
 current data is:task1
 current data is:task2
 data to be delete is present : task2
todonew.js:28 data deleted is undefined

Command : list the elements in todo 

 task2

Comment: Well if you remove the last one... then that slot will become undefined because the array length is now one less and nothing exists at that index now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the unwanted elements

```js
const todos = [ 'bla', 'ble', 'bli', 'foo', 'blo', 'blu', 'bly' ];
const search = 'foo';

const filtered = todos.filter(elem => elem !== search);

console.log(filtered);
```

Note that the original array will remain unchanged

Comment: what if I want to make changes to my existing list only?

Comment: Well, your current list shouldn't be `const` and it can be achieved like this : `todos = todos.filter(elem => elem !== search);`

Answer (score 1):

```js
search = "def";
let todo = ["task1", "abc", "eyg7eg", "ugfuegf7uegf", "def"];
todo.forEach(function (elem, i = 0) {
  if (elem === search) todo.splice(i, 1);
  i++;
});
```

used for each for iteration the whole array to find the desired element, then if element === search is true then use splice to delete that element

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @Nirob, your answer works fine, but, because of the *foreach*, it will go across the whole array every time (for instance, even if you would like to delete just the first element), so it is quite inefficient. You could use **some** or **every** instead, which allow 'break' the foreach. On the other hand, maybe it's better to 'get' the new **Fat Arrow** notation, more and more used every day: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/arrow-function

Answer (score 0):

Your code had 2 problems:

1. It was not deleting the right element (you should do splice(j,1), not splice(todos[j],1)
2. It was trying to get the value of the deleted element once it had been already deleted.

Fixing theses 2 things, your code works fine, just like this:

```js
let todos = ['task1', 'abc', 'def'];
let search = prompt('what index do you want to remove');

 for(let j=0;j<todos.length;j++){

    let currentData = todos[j];

    console.log(`current data is:${currentData}`);

    if(todos[j] === search){

        console.log(`data to be delete is ${search}`)

        currentData = todos.splice(j,1);

        console.log(`data deleted was ${currentData}`)
    }
}
```

For instance, **CONSOLE EXIT for 'abc' searched**:

```
current data is:task1

current data is:abc

data to be delete is abc

data deleted was abc
```

[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-e2otm9?file=index.js) I leave you a working copy of your own code with all that fixes.

---

As an *Extra*, I give a different version "mixing" several of others mates answers:

```js
const todos = ['task1', 'abc', 'def'];;
const search = 'abc';

todos.some( 
   (item, index) => { if (item === search) { todos.splice(index, 1); return true;} }
);

console.log(todos);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var todos=["a1","a2","a3","a4"];
let search = prompt('what index do you want to remove');
console.warn("BEFORE")
console.warn(todos)
for(let j=0;j<todos.length;j++){
  console.log(`current data is:${todos[j]}`);
  if(todos[j] === search){
      console.log(`data to be delete is present`)
    todos.splice(j,1);
    console.log(`data deleted is ${search}`)
  }
}
console.warn("AFTER")
console.warn(todos)
```

You can run the code above, or Just change your for loop with

```
for(let j=0;j<todos.length;j++){
    console.log(`current data is:${todos[j]}`);
  if(todos[j] === search){
      console.log(`data to be delete is present`)
      todos.splice(j,1);
      console.log(`data deleted is ${search}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the filter method

```
const todos = [ 'bla', 'ble', 'bli', 'foo', 'blo', 'blu', 'bly' ];
const search = 'foo';
```

Assuming the above is your todo, and the search item you want to remove from the todo

```
 todos.filter(
 (tod)=> tod !=search
 )
```

The filter method returns an array so , you can store it in a variable.
learn more about the filter method

[Filter Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)